# (Python) Converting a dictionary to a list?

Tags: python

So I have this dictionary:

```
ScoreDict = {"Blue": {'R1': 89, 'R2': 80},
            "Brown": {'R1': 61, 'R2': 77},
            "Purple": {'R1': 60, 'R2': 98},
            "Green": {'R1': 74, 'R2': 91},
            "Red": {'R1': 87, 'Lon': 74}}
```

Is there any way how I can convert this dictionary into a list like this:

```
ScoreList = [['Blue', 89, 80], ['Brown', 61, 77], 
['Purple', 60, 98], ['Green', 74, 91], ['Red', 87, 74]]
```

I'm not too familiar with dictionaries, so I really need some help here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the order of the numbers matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```
ScoreList = [[key] + value.values() for key, value in ScoreDict.iteritems()]
```

In a loop form it probably makes more sense:

```
ScoreList = []

for key, value in ScoreDict.iteritems():
  temp = []

  temp.append(key)
  temp.extend(value.values())

  ScoreList.append(temp)
```

The main problem you will face is that dictionaries aren't ordered. The elements are indexed by their hashes, which means that `value.values()` won't return the dictionary's values in any specific order.

Comment: Thank you @Blender! This works perfectly! Order doesn't really matter in this context, so it's all good!

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't keep the numbers in their original order as I don't see any logical ordering there.

```
>>> ScoreDict = {"Blue": {'R1': 89, 'R2': 80},
            "Brown": {'R1': 61, 'R2': 77},
            "Purple": {'R1': 60, 'R2': 98},
            "Green": {'R1': 74, 'R2': 91},
            "Red": {'R1': 87, 'Lon': 74}}
>>> [[k]+i.values() for k,i in ScoreDict.iteritems()]
[['Blue', 89, 80], ['Brown', 61, 77], ['Green', 74, 91], ['Red', 74, 87], ['Purple', 60, 98]]
```

Comment: I posted a similar but less elegant solution, I think it's important to note that this **does not** work if you are counting on the 2nd and 3rd items of the list being in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

Not reliably. There is no reason why the keys would remain in that order, hence it is impossible to assure that you can get that list from that dictionary.

Comment: I was going to say that the keys could be sorted, but then I saw that not all the nested dict keys were identical.

Comment: OrderedDict from collections package could be used to get the initialized order of keys in the dictionary, yes ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking if you are using a normal dictionary, the order would not be preserved. If you want the order to be preserved, you better use an Ordered Dict.

First Assuming, you do not need to preserved the order, then, you can do something like this to get the desired output

```
>>> [([k]+v.values()) for k,v in ScoreDict.items()]
[['Blue', 89, 80], ['Brown', 61, 77], ['Green', 74, 91], ['Red', 74, 87], ['Purple', 60, 98]]
>>>
```

But if you are serious about the order, your original data should be organized as OrderedDict. And here is an example to do it

```
>>> ScoreDict
OrderedDict([('Blue', OrderedDict([('R1', 89), ('R2', 80)])), ('Brown', OrderedDict([('R1', 61), ('R2', 77)])), ('Purple', OrderedDict([('R1', 60), ('R2', 98)])), ('Green', OrderedDict([('R1', 74), ('R2', 91)])), ('Red', OrderedDict([('R1', 87), ('R2', 74)]))])
```

and you can easily see, how applying the above solution would give the same result but preserving the order

```
>>> [([k]+v.values()) for k,v in ScoreDict.items()]
[['Blue', 89, 80], ['Brown', 61, 77], ['Purple', 60, 98], ['Green', 74, 91], ['Red', 87, 74]]
```

Answer (score 0):

(This is ***extremely*** fragile!)

```
ScoreList = [[colour, rs["R1"], rs["R2" if "R2" in rs else "Lon"]] for colour, rs in ScoreDict.items()]
```

This goes through each key-value pair in `ScoreDict` and creates the list from it. The important function here is `.items()` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)).

(Note, in Python 2.x `.iteritems` should be used instead of `.items` to avoid constructing an intermediate list.)

Comment: `ScoreDict['Red']` doesn't have a `'R2'` entry.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, ah, didn't notice that! Thanks :)